# Creating correct PDF using JPEG figure files

Tags: graphics, pdf, jpeg

Here follows a sample LaTex code

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\maketitle

This is a test text.

\begin{figure} 
\centering
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[bb=0 0 2291 2387]{frac.jpg}}
\caption{caption.}
\label{tst}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figure in JPEG format can be found [enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/rwaafshgv0ba690/frac.jpg)

When I compile the code figure is too small! Why? What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions on how to obtain the PDF file with the correct sized graph?

Even when I use directly the PDFLaTex the PDf output is again the the same with the small graph.

My PDF output can be viewed [enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/kewx4ci2oi40fkg/Test2.pdf). See how small is the figure placed at the left bottom.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you not use `pdflatex` directly`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Even when I use `pdflatex` directly adding `\pdfoutput=1` at the begging of the document the size of the figure is too small placed at the left bottom.

Comment: Your pdf output is produced by pdfTeX 1.40.11, which is quite old. Please update. And an MWE with `article` or `standalone` would be appreciated.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I edited my question including a simpler exaple with standard `article`. How can I update pdflatex? I have the version 2.9 of MikTex under Windows XP SP3.

Comment: don't use the `bb` option with pdflatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Now the output is fine. Please post a quick answer so as to accept it.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z: Windows *XP*? Update your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `bb` option with pdflatex (You should have a warning about that in the log)

```
    Option `bb' does not make sense,
    using `viewport' instead%
```